# merge two sub-documents in two collections in pymongo

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have two collection in db, called type1 and type2.

type1 collection:

```
{_id:"",md5:"",result:[
                        {from:"",
                         raw:{rects:
                                    [{h:"1",
                                      w:"2",
                                      properties:{type1:["111"]}
                                     }]
                             }
                        }
                      ]}
```

type2 collection:

```
{_id:"",md5:"",result:[
                        {from:"",
                         raw:{rects:
                                    [{h:"1",
                                      w:"2",
                                      properties:{type2:["111"]}
                                     }]
                             }
                        }
                      ]}
```

i want to merge 2 collections like full outer join on md5 in sql, and produce a new properties, which has 2 type (type1,type2) in an array.

Comment: the outcome's properties is like properties: {type1:["1111"],type2:["222"]}

Comment: Use $lookup in aggregation pipeline which performs a left outer join between two collections.

Comment: i have tried the $lookup, but i want to realize full outer join. so i want to try some other ways.

Comment: what is the relation between `type1 collection` and `type2 collection`, post that in your sample document shown in the question